# Jquery Datatable Checkbox Selection with Row Click Redirect

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a Jquery Datatable with the datatable select addon -- https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/.

I am using checkbox to multi-select the row, this is the setting:

```
            "select": {
                'style': 'multi',
                'selector': 'td:first-child'    //only checkbox can select row
            },
```

This works well. Only when I click on the checkbox will it select the row. What I need next is when I click on the rest of the row (any other place except for the checkbox), I need to go to a special URL based on the row clicked. I added this:

```
        $('#MyTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            console.log(table.row(this).data()["Id"]);
        });
```

This works well too as I am able to get the unique Id value for the row clicked.

Now the problem is the row click trumps checkbox select. In other words, even if I click on the checkbox, it still redirects the users. I need to let the checkbox not be part of the row click, how do I do that? The checkbox is the first column, here is part of my column definitions:

```
                "columnDefs": [
                {
                    'targets': 0,
                    'checkboxes': {
                        'selectRow': true
                    }
                },
```

I also tried to see if the tr hasClass('selected'), but the select action occurs after the click action, therefore, it's always false at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer:

```
  $('#MyTable tbody').on('click', 'tr td:not(:nth-child(1))', function () {
        console.log(table.row(this).data()["Id"]);
    });
```

This will exclude the first column in row click event.